# JPEG encoder unavailable for GDI+ on mono (CentOS)

Tags: c#, mono, centos, gdi+, centos6

I have installed mono 3.2.6 on CentOS 6.4. I need to create JPEG bitmap, but the following method does not return proper mime type:

```
ImageCodecInfo jpegImageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().FirstOrDefault(x => x.MimeType.Equals("image/jpeg"));
```

`ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()` returns only `image/bmp` and `image/png`. I already have installed libjpeg-turbo and libjpeg-turbo-devel with libjpeg-turbo-static, but with no effect. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally we managed to solve the problem.

Problem was that `libgdiplus` could not find the proper version of `libjpeg.so`. The newest version of `libjpeg.so` provided with `libjpeg-turbo` was **62** while the required version is **90**. Finally we used the newest version of `libjpeg` available at http://www.ijg.org/.

If you encounter similar problem you should first install proper (**>=90**) version of `libjpeg.so` then copy it to `/usr/lib64/` and then recompile `libgdiplus`. That should fix it.